# How java compiler solved lambda return type while Predicate's method can only return boolean?

Tags: java, lambda

Things I can't understand is that we know java doesn't support dynamic type even use Lambda, and it's compiled to Predictor during compile time.

Things I can't understand is that Predicator's default method only can return boolean, while Lambda expression can return anything. How is this archived?

Comment: What is a `Predicator`? And Lambdas are compiled to implement a functional interface.

Comment: "this question look like some others but different". Whenever you say anything like this in a question, you should explain **what you have already found** and **how its different from what you're asking**.

Comment: He probably means `java.util.function.Predicate`.
Anyway, I  believe that this question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow, because the answer would be an explanation of how lambdas work in java.

Comment: i mean "java.util.function.Predicate"

Answer (score 1):

`while Lambda expression can return anything.` This is wrong

**A lambda expression is written to a corresponding abstract method in a function interface**

Considering `Predicate` as an example, lambda expression will be written to corresponding abstract method which is `boolean test(T t)`

**From java docs** [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) with an clear example

> A functional interface is any interface that contains only one abstract method. (A functional interface may contain one or more default methods or static methods.) Because a functional interface contains only one abstract method, you can omit the name of that method when you implement it. To do this, instead of using an anonymous class expression, you use a lambda expression, which is highlighted in the following method invocation:

Refer : Approach 5: Specify Search Criteria Code with a Lambda Expression

Refer : Approach 6: Use Standard Functional Interfaces with Lambda Expressions